# Node.js - написание модуля состоящего из нескольких файлов

Tags: node.js

Пишу модуль для node.js и одного файла уже не хватает. Хочу подключить подмодуль в "пространство имен" текущего модуля. Что-то типа include в c++. Как нужно изменить код чтобы это заработало?

variables.js:

```
var a = 3;
```

index.js:

```
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Если делать через require то нужно будет обращаться через промежуточный объект, а это уже не очень удобно.

Comment: `require` - единственный путь, т.к. каждый файл в node.js создает под себя отдельную, изолированную область видимости

Comment: @Dmitriy, подскажите, есть ли в node.js объект, который отвечает за текущию облать видимости? Если да, то мы можем в пробежаться по всем членам подмодуля и этому объекту присвоить все содержимое подмодуля. Так можно сделать с globals, но засорять его  было бы глупо. Способ слить все объекты всех подфайлов в один я нашел: https://gist.github.com/matteocontrini/2da2f6ceefbaa3ea9384

Comment: @Fixturessd да, обратиться к текущей области видимости вы можете с помощью `this`